# DbContext.Save on parent with child objects throws "Conflicting changes detected"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a parent/child hierarchy of which I want to insert a new parent into a DbContext and have it automatically persist the child objects. The relationship is a One-to-many, where each parent can at 0 or more columns.

But whenever I call DbContext.Save(parent) I receive a 'Conflicting changes detected. This may happen when trying to insert multiple entities with the same key.'. When I strip the parent of the child columns it saves fines, so I'm assuming this is related to the child objects not having their primary key set. How do I tell the EntityFramework to save my hierarchy properly?

My classes:

```
public class ExcelTemplate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int FirstDataRow { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TemplateColumn> Columns { get; set; }

    public ExcelTemplate()
    {
        Columns = new List<TemplateColumn>();
    }
}

public class TemplateColumn
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public int MetricTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual MetricType MetricType { get; set; }

    public int TemplateId { get; set; }
    public virtual ExcelTemplate Template { get; set; }
}
```

And the configurations:

```
public class ExcelTemplateConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ExcelTemplate>
{
    public ExcelTemplateConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id)
            .Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsRequired();

        HasMany(t => t.Columns)
            .WithRequired(c => c.Template)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.TemplateId);
    }
}

public class TemplateColumnConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<TemplateColumn>
{
    public TemplateColumnConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(c => c.Id)
            .Property(c => c.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        HasRequired(tpl => tpl.MetricType)
            .WithRequiredDependent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Do the `ExcelTemplate.Id` and `TemplateColumn.Id` have Identity specification? Are you setting the `Id` property properly?
2. Are you setting the `ExcelTemplate` property of the `TemplateColumn` objects to the `ExcelTemplate` parent?

Something like:

```
ExcelTemplate t = new ExcelTemplate();
//init template code...skip

TemplateColumn c = new TemplateColumn();
//init template column code...skip
c.ExcelTemplate = t;//this is the line I am asking if you are doing.
```

Comment: Both the ExcelTemplate.Id and TemplateColumn.Id are set to DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity(see the configuration in my snippet above, it is the last bit of the code). In my ExcelTemplateRepository.Save() I iterate over all Columns and set the parent object: foreach (var c in tpl.Columns) c.Template = tpl;

Comment: I currently use a bit of a hack to get this working, but it is far from desirable. I added an DbSet<TemplateColumn> to the DbContext and currently insert first the parent and then the children but this is undesirable as it is a lot more work and kinda beats of point of having an ORM mapper.

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce this in a simple project that containt only the EF6 Context and some code that creates your entities? Did you get the same result?

Comment: I have now and I can safely conclude that the problem persists. I'm kinda assuming I made a booboo in my configuration somehow and am confusing the EF but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Perhaps it is note worthy that I am using MySQL as host to talk to.

Comment: In your code, do you set the MetricType property or just the MetricTypeId property?

Comment: I actually tried both. Thing is, whenever I generated a new database migration, the EF *always* made a foreign key from the TemplateColumn.Id to the MetricsType.Id column.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the culprit through trial-and-error, because the problem persisted when I only tried to store a TemplateColumn by itself.

The problem was to remove this line of code from the TemplateColumn configuration and let the entity framework map by convention:

```
HasRequired(tpl => tpl.MetricType)
    .WithRequiredDependent();
```

Any idea why this didn't work?

Comment: Maybe you can move this to your question, because in fact it narrows down your original question. If you show the code in which you make the changes there's a good chance we can tackle this.